# maintain key format when copying values from one object to another

Tags: javascript

The following code demonstrates an issue that has surfaced while writing an app using the Vue framework for the front end.  The issue is really a JS one though.

Here is the data object needed by the Vue component:

```
let data = { accountId: '', prospectId: '', address: '', city: '', state: '' }
```

and here is an object containing a row of data from the database:

```
    const retrieved = {
    "ProspectID": "4",
    "AccountID": "1003",
    "Address": "E2828 Highway 14",
    "City": "Madison",
    "State": "WI",
    "Created": "2021-02-27 11:49:33.523",
    "Updated": "2021-02-27 11:49:33.523"
}
```

It is necessary to copy *some* of the values from `retrieved` into `data`.  The current way of doing the copy is the following:

```
data.accountId = retrieved.AccountID;
data.prospectId = retrieved.ProspectID;
data.address = retrieved.Address;
data.city = retrieved.City;
data.state = retrieved.State;
console.log('data', data);
```

The result of the above code is the desired outcome and it looks like this:
[image]

I'm looking for a more efficient way to do the copying because it's tedious when there are many key/value pairs involved.

I've tried this:

```
data = { ...data, ...retrieved };
console.log('data', data);
```

which results in this
[image]

which basically unions all the key/value pairs together.  Not the desired outcome.

It is critical that the key names in `data` keep their exact names and no extra key/value pairs get added to `data`.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a copy of `retrieved` and converting all the key names to lowercase, then populating the values for `data` works -

```
const r = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(retrieved).map(([k, v]) => [k.toLowerCase(), v])
);

// Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
//  data[key] = r[key.toLowerCase()];
// });

Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k] = r[k.toLowerCase()]);

console.log('r', r);
console.log('data', data);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the capitalization is different, spread won't work. You'll have to iterate over an array mapping the properties on the different objects to each other:

```
const propsToCopy = {
  // data    // retrieved
  accountId: 'AccountID',
  prospectId: 'ProspectID',
  // ...
};
for (const [dataProp, retrievedProp] of Object.entries(propsToCopy)) {
  data[dataProp] = retrieved[retrievedProp];
}
```

That said, having slightly different property names for the same data like this seems very strange, since it makes the code a lot more convoluted than it needs to be and greatly increases the risk of typo-based problems, when a property is capitalized but doesn't need to be, or vice-versa. Consider if you can use just a single property name format instead, if at all possible; then the `propsToCopy` could be reduced to an array:

```
const propsToCopy = ['accountId', 'prospectId', /* ... */ ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in order [to intercept all settings of values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set). This allows only setting known values and ignoring anything else.

To make the setting of the property preserve the case, we can just lookup the original key case-insensitively and use the original one.

Finally, using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will call all the setters on the target which means that the proxy can intercept these calls:

```js
const eqCaseInsensitive = a => b =>
  a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase();
  
const handler = {
  set(target, prop, value, receiver) {
    const key = Object.keys(target)
      .find(eqCaseInsensitive(prop));
      
    if (key !== undefined) {
      return Reflect.set(target, key, value, receiver);
    }
      
    return true;
  }
}

let data = { accountId: '', prospectId: '', address: '', city: '', state: '' }

const retrieved = {
    "ProspectID": "4",
    "AccountID": "1003",
    "Address": "E2828 Highway 14",
    "City": "Madison",
    "State": "WI",
    "Created": "2021-02-27 11:49:33.523",
    "Updated": "2021-02-27 11:49:33.523"
}

Object.assign(new Proxy(data, handler), retrieved);

console.log(data);
```

This can further be converted to a helper function that is analogous to `Object.assign()` and allow for as many sources as you wish. To save some processing time, there is no need to do a full search for each property assignment - a simple lookup map can be precomputed that holds lowercase property names as keys and normal case property names as values:

```js
const assignOnlyKnownProps = (target, ...sources) => {
  const known = new Map(
    Object.keys(target)
      .map(key => [key.toLowerCase(), key])
  );
 
  const handler = {
    set(target, prop, value, receiver) {
      const lookup = prop.toLowerCase();
      
      if (known.has(lookup)) {
        Reflect.set(target, known.get(lookup), value, receiver);
      }

      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return Object.assign(new Proxy(target, handler), ...sources);
}

let data = { accountId: '', prospectId: '', address: '', city: '', state: '' }

const retrieved = {
    "ProspectID": "4",
    "AccountID": "1003",
    "Address": "E2828 Highway 14",
    "City": "Madison",
    "State": "WI",
    "Created": "2021-02-27 11:49:33.523",
    "Updated": "2021-02-27 11:49:33.523"
}

assignOnlyKnownProps(data, retrieved);

console.log(data);
```